# Metaprogramming in Elixir

Tags: elixir, metaprogramming

```
defmodule BBB do
  IO.puts "BBB"
  defmacro hh do
    IO.puts "hh in BBB"
  end
end

defmodule AAA do
  IO.puts "AAA"
  require BBB
  BBB.hh
end
```

Why is the output:

```
BBB
hh in BBB
AAA
```

I'm really confused by the compiling process in Elixir.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I'm assuming you expected `hh in BBB` to be after `AAA`. The reason it's the reverse of that is because when `AAA` is compiled, the macro `hh` is first expanded. Since `hh` prints a value directly instead of returning a quoted fragment that prints, it's executed before any expressions in the `AAA` module are executed.

If you change `hh` to be a normal `def` instead of `defmacro`:

```
def hh do
  IO.puts "hh in BBB"
end
```

or you change `defmacro hh` to return quoted AST which prints the string:

```
defmacro hh do
  quote do
    IO.puts "hh in BBB"
  end
end
```

the output will be `AAA` first and then `hh in BBB`.